# Default packer builder without using -only option

Tags: docker, packer

I have multiple builders section in my packer template, by default this builds both builder on the cloud provider at the same time.

However, if I want to build only the "amazon-ebs" type on the cloud, and use "docker" type locally I can get this with done with `packer build -only=rails <path/to/template.yaml>`.

Is there a way I can set the default builder to "rails" in the template without using the `-only=rails` from the packer CLI option.

```
  "builders": [
    {
      "name": "rails"
      "type": "amazon-ebs",
      "region": "us-west-2",
      "source_ami": "{{user `rails_web_ami`}}",
      "instance_type": "m3.medium",
      "ami_name": "deploy-rails-web-{{user `sha`}}",
      "availability_zone": "us-west-2c",
      "ssh_username": "centos",
      "ssh_pty" : "true"
    },
    {
      "name": "docker-local",
      "type": "docker",
      "pull": "true",
      "image": "askb/centos7:latest",
      "run_command": [ "-d", "-t", "-i", "{{.Image}}", "/bin/bash"],
      "changes": [
        "WORKDIR /tmp",
        "EXPOSE 8080",
        "USER jenkins",
        "LABEL buildtime {{isotime \"20060102-150405.000\"}}"
      ],
      "commit": true
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": ...
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to use `-only` there is nothing like "default builder".